# Why BackgroundWorder DoWork catch only some exceptions?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I know that `BackgroundWorker` eats unhanded exceptions and will pass them to `RunWorkerCompleted` `e.Error` property and the correct way of handling exceptions is by checking `e.Error != null`.

In the method for `DoWork` event, I have several `try` `catch` blocks but only some of them like `FailedOperationException` is working.If my code tries to access a class in an unavilable dll a `FileNotFoundException` is thrown which won't be caupht by neighter `FileNotFoundException` or `Exception` catch blocks. Instead of that, it goes to `e.Error` property of `RunWorkerCompleted`.

Why only some of the exception aren caught?

Code:

```
    try
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.CharityConnectionString);
        String dataSource = connection.DataSource;

        if (((ActionType)e.Argument) == ActionType.Backup)
        {
            try
            {
                lblWait.Text = "Starting backup operation ...";
                ServerConnection serverConnection = new ServerConnection(dataSource);
                Server sqlServer = new Server(serverConnection); // The exception is thrown here
                String originalBackupPath = fileName;
                BackupDeviceItem backupDevice = new BackupDeviceItem(originalBackupPath, DeviceType.File);
                Backup backup = new Backup();
                backup.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
                backup.Database = "Charity";
                backup.Devices.Add(backupDevice);
                backup.Initialize = true;
                backup.Checksum = true;
                backup.ContinueAfterError = true;
                backup.Incremental = false;
                backup.LogTruncation = BackupTruncateLogType.Truncate;
                backup.SqlBackup(sqlServer);
                MessageBox.Show("Backup was successfull", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException ex) // this catch doesn't work for FileNotFoundException exceptions
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error in operation" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            catch (FailedOperationException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Access to the selected folder is denied", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            catch (Exception) // and this catch doesn't work for FileNotFoundException, too
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error in operation", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error in operation", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
```

The `FileNotFoundException` with message "*Could not load file or assembly. Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo*" is only displayed in `e.Error`. I know how to resolve this exception by private installation of assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have the exception wrong. Are you looking at an `InnerException` in `e.Error`?

This code works as expected:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += (s, e) =>
        {
            try
            {
                throw new FileNotFoundException();
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("FileNotFoundException caught");
            }
        };

        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
                Console.WriteLine("RunWorkerCompleted error is {0}", e);
        };

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        while (worker.IsBusy)
            Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: The InnerException of e.Error is null, and when the JIT compiler reach the ServerConnection it throws an execption of type FileNotFoundException (the required dll is not found). I don't throw any exception manually.